# Is there some easy way to find a list of all macros I've written in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I don't remember which file it was that I wrote the macro I'm looking for in, so is there some way to get a list of all the macros I've written on my computer?

Comment: A search for `*.xlsm` will return all macro-enabled workbooks, if that's any help.

Comment: It did help. Thank you. Seems whichever file it was it is gone unfortunately.

Comment: Try also `*.xls` in case the macro was stored in Excel 2003 or older format.

Comment: Or `*.xlsb`, if you have used binary.

Comment: Found it! Thanks. Didn't realize you could save macros in .xls-files but apparently that's what I'd been doing.